# Line with alternate chevrons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style

I'm looking for a way to create this line style in QGIS:

[image: wayleave symbol]

Is it possible? I can't find a way, but wanted to check whether I had missed something.

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: 2.1 Pisa at the moment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get something like it by selecting 'Marker line' under symbol layer type in one of the style dialogs, then layering/altering three of the simple markers. You could then either add a font marker to the line, label it, or create a second line on top of the first with the 'WL' annotation. Does that help? [image]